# NGINX failing once a week, responds with 499 until NIGNX reload

Tags: nginx, iis, amazon-elb

I have an NGINX instance set up acting as a reverse proxy for several applications, each setup as their own server within the NGINX config.

The configuration is currently very minimal:

```
listen                  80;
listen                  443 ssl;
server_name             example.com;
access_log              /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;

location ~ .*/url1/.* {
                allow xx.0.0.0/8; 
                deny all;

                proxy_pass              http://aws-balender-cname-url;
}


location ~ / {
                proxy_pass              http://aws-balencer-cname-url;
}
```

One of these applications stops working once at week at roughly the same time, when I check the NGINX access log, its responding with mainly 499 (client closed request) response codes with the occasional 502 and 504. All the other applications are fine.

The NGINX error logs have this entry:

> upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to

If I look at the upstream server (Microsoft IIS, via an AWS ELB) hosting the application it looks fine, its not under load, the requests just stop coming through.

How I have been resolving the situation is to, reload the NGINX config and the problem stops occurring, but this a poor fix.

Any recommendations on what the problem is? Or how to diagnose it?

Is there anything in the NGINX AWS-ELB IIS chain that could cause an issue?

Comment: Why have you put a proxy in front of ELB? ELB IP address changes sometimes, are you using IP or cname? 499 is "client closed request" ( https://httpstatuses.com/499 ). Could it be slow requests ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613452/nginx-issues-http-499-error-after-60-seconds-despite-config-php-and-aws )? Please edit your question to note what solutions you've tried (you've tried something right?) and why they didn't work.

Comment: @Tim Its legacy, we put NGINX in front of an existing setup that already had ELB. The reference to ELB is a CNAME, and all the other applications dont get this problem. I haven't tried much, because I don't understand why its happening and it only happens once a week, so its hard to experiment.  It didn't happen before nginx was put in place - what would you try?

Comment: Given what that link I found says I'd try crafting a request that takes longer than your Nginx timeout and see if that reproduces it. Next I'd do some more research, find some more theories, and test them.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing. Restarting nginx clears it up. I'm proxying from one AWS EC2 instance behind a load balancer, to another behind the same load balancer, proxying to it's external endpoint. I see log entries like this one, returning a 499: > 96.246.47.76 - - [28/Jun/2021:15:41:53 +0000] "POST /V1.2/access_token/portal/ HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "https://nnnnn/vue_admin/"
> "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36
> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36" I'm making logrotate.d restart nginx nightly as a kludge, but I don't have a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is still a open question, and I have found the reason, here it is.

The `proxy_pass` in your config is set to a DNS name and not an IP address.

And when `nginx` starts, it resolves the DNS name and caches its IP address internally and keeps using it until the next restart.

The solution is to use `resolver` directive with valid parameter.

Refer [Resolver directive for setting up nginx reverse proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/875150/resolver-directive-for-setting-up-nginx-reverse-proxy)

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Thank you for answering this unanswered question. Hopefully, the OP will return to mark this as the answer. Generally, StackExchange sites prefer to have relevant steps to answer a question included in an answer, even when the is to another question in the same site.

Comment: Thank you this seems a right direction, will try it.