# Resolver directive for setting up nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx

When setting up nginx as a reverse proxy with a gunicorn application server (a typical 1-to-1 mapping between the backend application server and nginx), I've configured the following:

```
upstream my_server {

  server unix:/home/user/folder/app/app.sock  fail_timeout=0;
}

location @https_proxy_to_app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://my_server;
}
```

This is prescribed by a lot of literature available on the subject. While this works, I have a couple of questions about it.

Firstly (and trivially), why the need to include `http://` in `proxy_pass http://my_server;`?

And secondly (and more importantly), do I need to set the `resolver` directive for this kind of a setup? I'm not using AWS' Elastic Load Balancer, and a lot of the [prescription](https://distinctplace.com/2017/04/19/nginx-resolver-explained/) [around](https://www.jethrocarr.com/2013/11/02/nginx-reverse-proxies-and-dns-resolution/) the `resolver` directive happens to revolve around AWS ELB. Can someone explain in layman's terms why and how I need to set it? Accidental server admin here, so need an expert opinion.

Note that I'm also using OSCP stapling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `resolver` directive should be used in cases where your upstream servers are defined with DNS names.

IP adresses for upstream servers are evaluated when nginx starts.

The caveat here is that if an IP address is changed for a DNS name, nginx will not be aware of that until it restarts.

The `resolver` directive takes care of this, by updating "transparently" the IP address for the upstream server when the cache defined (`valid=time`) is expired.

In your case, where you use a Unix Socket and not a DNS name, this directive would be useless.

---

Why specify `http` for a Unix Socket ?
I admit i am not 100% sure what the reason is.

Surely mainly because the `proxy_pass` directive requires that both, protocol and address, are defined for the proxied server, and that nginx allows only `http` and `https` protocols.

> proxy_pass *URL*;
>
> Sets the protocol and address of a proxied server and an optional URI
>   to which a location should be mapped. As a protocol, “http” or “https”
>   can be specified.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Comment: 1) I see, so `resolver` is basically used when the upstream is remote 2) Then if you're directing all traffic to `http` as a policy, shouldn't this be `https://my_server;` instead?

Comment: 1) yes and no : nevermind if the upstream is remote or local, if it is 
 defined with an ip address instead of a dns name, no need for `resolver` directive. 2) Not sure you can use https here, i am searching around

Comment: @Hassan Baig : for 2) as you have an already socket app to test, you could test and share with us your results about `https` to your socket ;)

Comment: I'm gonna give it a shot and report it here